# The meaning of 蹴り脚 and translation of the sentence

Tags: translation

I cannot completely grasp the meaning of 蹴り脚 in the following sentence. I would translate it as "the hitting leg" or rather "the leg which is doing an act of hitting"(not the best way to express it but I guess it explained the point), however in this sentence it is unclear why it is used with jumping(跳躍). So I tried to make some sort of a translation, and I would really appreciate if you correct my mistakes.

"After-effect from the jump which forced floor to collapse (with the leg hit(蹴り脚で)), and primary lights(原色光) of 斑に乱舞する(?) and covered in blood disco ball, are the things that reflected in my sight- Inside there(その中にあって),  jet black longcoat flutter like a condensated(凝縮した) black, gouging out throw the darkness."

> ただ視界に映るのは、蹴り脚でフロアを陥没させた跳躍の爪痕と、斑に乱舞する血塗られたミラーボールの原色光ーー。その中にあって尚昏く、闇を抉り抜いて凝縮したのごとき漆黒ロングコートが翻る

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ただ視界に映るのは、蹴｛け｝り脚｛あし｝でフロアを陥没させた跳躍の爪痕と、斑｛まだら｝に乱舞｛らんぶ｝する血塗られたミラーボールの原色｛げんしょく｝光｛ひかり｝－－。

You have more or less the right idea with 蹴り足 - a leg that hits. Now, when one jumps (跳躍), what must one's leg do? It must push off of (i.e. hit) the floor, of course. Depending on context, it might even be reasonable to say that one "kicks" off the floor, depending on the exact way in which one jumps.

I see that Weblio apparently gives "primary lights" as a translation for [原色光](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%8E%9F%E8%89%B2%E5%85%89). This doesn't mean anything in English, of course. When presented by a seemingly nonsensical translation for a kanji compound, it often helps to try breaking the kanji compound down into smaller pieces and seeing if you can assemble any meaning for them. As it happens, [原色](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%8E%9F%E8%89%B2) means "primary colors" (e.g. red, yellow, blue), and so it follows that 原色光 means "lights in primary colors". Note that I am not entirely sure what the reading of 原色光 is actually supposed to be, though げんしょくひかり is my best guess. Other possibilities: げんしょっこう, げんしょくびかり.

[斑](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E6%96%91) (lots of other readings, but I think this one is まだら) means "spots or speckles", and so 斑に means "in spots or speckles". [乱舞](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E4%B9%B1%E8%88%9E%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)する means "to dance wildly". So, 斑に乱舞する gives us "to dance wildly in a spotted or speckled manner".

So now, we can translate the first sentence (somewhat woodily, and with some annotations).

> [All]{ただ} [that I could see]{視界に映る} was the [damage]{爪痕} done to [the floor]{フロア} when (someone) [jumped off]{跳躍} it, [the strength of whose leg]{蹴り脚} [caused it to collapse]{陥没させた}, as well as the [speckles]{斑} of [primary-colored light]{原色光} emanating from the [bloodstained]{血塗られた} [disco ball]{ミラーボール}, [dancing wildly]{乱舞する}.

Here, I've interpolated "the strength of whose leg" for 蹴り脚, though you could alternately do something woodier, like "the floor which was caused to collapse when [someone] pushed off from it as part of a jump" or something.

---

On to the second sentence.

> その中にあって尚昏く、闇を抉り抜いて凝縮｛ぎょうしゅく｝したのごとき漆黒ロングコートが翻る。

You have this pretty much under control. I'll just offer my own take on it for comparison.

> [And amongst all that]{その中にあって}, [darker still]{尚昏く}, [flapped]{翻る} a [long coat]{ロングコート} that [cut through]{抉り抜いて} the [darkness]{闇}, a coat which was [like]{ごとき} [condensed]{凝縮した} [blackness]{漆黒}.